# Converting data from wide to long format using reshape

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have got a csv file in the wide format that I need to change to long format. I have just given the first 3 rows.

```
CODEA   C45 ragek   ra80    ra98    ... Obese14 Overweight14 Obese21 hibp14 hibp21 Overweight21
1   1   NA  3   4   1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA      NA  NA
2   3   2   3   3   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
3   4   2   3   6   1   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

This goes on . `Obese 14 (Yes/No); Overweight(yes/no)`etc.

```
> names(Copy.of.BP_2)

 [1] "CODEA"  "C45"                     "ragek"                   "ra80"              
 [5] "ra98"   "CBCLAggressionAt1410"    "CBCLInternalisingAt1410" "Obese14"              
 [9] "Overweight14"   "Overweight21"    "Obese21"                 "hibp14"               
[13] "hibp21"
```

It has 6898 observations and 13 variables

I am trying to organise this data in the stacked format; I thought the following one would be a good option. I am not sure  how to combine `obese` and `overweight` category as the original long version has `obese14`, `overweight14`, `obese 21` and `overweight21` as 4 different categories.

```
CODEA ...  time         Obese        Overweight      HiBP

           14 
           21
           14
           21 ... etc
```

I gave the syntax as:

```
BP.stack1=reshape(Copy.of.BP_2, 
   timevar="time",direction="long",
   varying=list(names(Copy.of.BP_2[8:13]),
   v.names="Obese","Overweight","HiBP",idvar=c("CODEA")
```

It does not seem to work, it gives a `+` sign and waits for further command.

Should I be using `melt` and `cast`?. I read the `reshape` package manual , but cannot understand it.

**edit**: question restructured

Comment: Sorry, I  am not sure how to create a smaller version( I am  a beginner)

Comment: @UshaGurunathan, see my answer for how to fix your attempt at using `reshape()`. You were actually *very* close.

Answer (score 3):

Sticking with base R `reshape()`, try the following.

I *think* that I have recreated your example data with the following:

```
Copy.of.BP_2 <- 
structure(list(CODEA = c(1, 3, 4), C45 = c(NA, 2, 2), ragek = c(3, 
3, 3), ra80 = c(4, 3, 6), ra98 = c(1, 1, 1), CBCLAggressionAt1410 = c(NA, 
0, NA), CBCLInternalisingAt1410 = c(NA, 0, NA), Obese14 = c(NA, 
0, NA), Overweight14 = c(NA, 0, NA), Overweight21 = c(NA, 1, 
NA), Obese21 = c(NA, 0, NA), hibp14 = c(NA, 0, NA), hibp21 = c(NA, 
0, NA)), .Names = c("CODEA", "C45", "ragek", "ra80", "ra98", 
"CBCLAggressionAt1410", "CBCLInternalisingAt1410", "Obese14", 
"Overweight14", "Overweight21", "Obese21", "hibp14", "hibp21"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

Copy.of.BP_2
#   CODEA C45 ragek ra80 ra98 CBCLAggressionAt1410 CBCLInternalisingAt1410
# 1     1  NA     3    4    1                   NA                      NA
# 2     3   2     3    3    1                    0                       0
# 3     4   2     3    6    1                   NA                      NA
#   Obese14 Overweight14 Overweight21 Obese21 hibp14 hibp21
# 1      NA           NA           NA      NA     NA     NA
# 2       0            0            1       0      0      0
# 3      NA           NA           NA      NA     NA     NA
```

First, for convenience, let's create a vector of the measure variables--the variables that we want to "stack" from wide to long format.

```
measurevars <- names(Copy.of.BP_2)[grepl("Obese|Overweight|hibp", 
                                         names(Copy.of.BP_2))]
```

Next, use `reshape()`, specifying the direction, the identification variable, and which variables "vary" with time (`measurevars`, from above).

```
BP_2_long <- reshape(Copy.of.BP_2, direction = "long", idvar="CODEA",
                     varying = measurevars, sep = "")
BP_2_long
#      CODEA C45 ragek ra80 ra98 CBCLAggressionAt1410 CBCLInternalisingAt1410
# 1.14     1  NA     3    4    1                   NA                      NA
# 3.14     3   2     3    3    1                    0                       0
# 4.14     4   2     3    6    1                   NA                      NA
# 1.21     1  NA     3    4    1                   NA                      NA
# 3.21     3   2     3    3    1                    0                       0
# 4.21     4   2     3    6    1                   NA                      NA
#      time Obese Overweight hibp
# 1.14   14    NA         NA   NA
# 3.14   14     0          0    0
# 4.14   14    NA         NA   NA
# 1.21   21    NA         NA   NA
# 3.21   21     0          1    0
# 4.21   21    NA         NA   NA
```

---

If you are only interested in the id column and the measure column, you can also add a `drop` argument into your `reshape()` command:

```
BP_2_long_2 <- reshape(
  Copy.of.BP_2, direction = "long", idvar="CODEA",
  varying = measurevars, sep = "",
  drop = !names(Copy.of.BP_2) %in% c(measurevars, "CODEA"))
BP_2_long_2
#      CODEA time Obese Overweight hibp
# 1.14     1   14    NA         NA   NA
# 3.14     3   14     0          0    0
# 4.14     4   14    NA         NA   NA
# 1.21     1   21    NA         NA   NA
# 3.21     3   21     0          1    0
# 4.21     4   21    NA         NA   NA
```

#### Update: Why your code doesn't work

Here is an argument-by-argument breakdown of what you tried with comments on how you can try to fix it.

```
BP.stack1 = 
reshape(Copy.of.BP_2,                    # Fine
timevar="time",                          # Fine
direction="long",                        # Fine
varying=list(names(Copy.of.BP_2)[8:13]), # Wrong. Use "varying = 8:13" instead
v.names="Obese","Overweight","HiBP",     # Wrong. This needs to be in c()
idvar=c("CODEA")                         # Almost... missing your closing ")"
```

Thus, to get a complete working command:

```
BP.stack1 = reshape(
  Copy.of.BP_2, 
  timevar="time", 
  direction="long", 
  varying=8:13, 
  v.names=c("Obese", "Overweight", "HiBP"),
  idvar=c("CODEA"))
```

I generally try to not depend too much on the column number since those are more likely to be rearranged than the columns are to be renamed. Hence my use of `grepl()` to match names according to a certain pattern.